# Delphi Change Metropolis UI font color

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, vcl-styles

Whenever i make a Metropolis UI project and try to change a Label font to any color other than white, nothing happens, and the colors are always White when i compile the project,
So is there anyway to change the color font?

I'm using Delphi XE5, VCL application.

Comment: That's to be expected. Did you read this: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Developing_Metropolis_UI_Applications

Comment: Are you using VCL o FireMonkey? What Delphi version?

Comment: Please can you put that information into the question. The VCL needs to go in the question, and XE5 as a tag: delphi-xe5. Please can you do the edit. As to the question, I presume what is happening is that your app is painted using VCL styles and that determines the appearance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To change the color of a `TLabel` under a VCL Metropolis App, you must remove the `seFont` element from the [`StyleElements`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/Vcl.Controls.TControl.StyleElements) property.

[image]

Comment: Presumably you could also use a different style to apply changes app-wide?